# Changing background color from within for loop? [ios]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change the background color by looping through a list of numerical values that each correspond to a color. For each integer in the list I want the background to change to that color, pause for a second, then change to the next color in the list. However, even though the entire list is being iterated through, the background color only seems to change to the color that is at the end of the list. What is something I can do so that the background will change for each item in the list?

The code below is executed when the user presses the play button:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    [self.mem addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random() % 3]];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                 animations:
     ^(void) {
         for (int i = 0; i < [self.mem count]; i++) {
             if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]) {
                 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
             } else if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
                 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
             } else if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]) {
                 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
             } else {
                 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
             }
         }
     }
                     completion:
     ^(BOOL finished) {
         if(finished){
         }
     }];
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! I have updated your method and you should be able to simple copy and paste it in.  See @Caleb's answer for an explanation.

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    static UIColor *color;
    // i is the ivar that saves the state in the color sequence
    static int i = 0;

    if (sender) {
        i = 0;
        [self.mem addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random() % 3]];
    }

    if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]) {
        color = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
        color = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else if ([self.mem objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]) {
        color = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        color = [UIColor cyanColor];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
        self.backgroundColor = color;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Only continue animating if the play button has not been pressed
        if (i < self.mem.count - 1) {
            i += 1;
            // trigger another change by calling play:
            [self play:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This would work better if the delay was based on the value of `i`. Otherwise all of the animations will run at the same time.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't believe the animations will all happen simultaneously since the method will not be called until the previous animation is completed.  After review, my example will in fact never end animating because an object is added to self.mem for each call so "i" will never be greater than self.mem.i.  I am not sure how to change this appropriately since I do not know blzn's reason for adding a value to the array whenever the button is pressed so I'll leave my example how it is for now.

Comment: Oops. I overlooked that each iteration is called from the completion block. Never mind. :)

Comment: thanks @JustinMoser for the code, it is very helpful even if it is never ending! This is the beginning of a simon says type game where the user will try to copy the combination of colors that appear on the screen. So each time the user successfully replicates the list of colors, the animation method should run again with an additional random color added to list.

Answer (score 0):

`-animateWithDuration:options:animations:` will perform the animation using whatever values you set last in the animation block -- it doesn't spend *`duration`* seconds on each change you make.

If you want to animate the background changing from one color to another to another, you need to do it in steps. Use the completion block to trigger another change (possibly just calling `-play:` again). You might want to save some state in an ivar to make it easier to know where you are in the color sequence.